# Encrypt password in add user form - Spring security

Tags: spring-mvc, encryption, spring-security, sha

I've used Spring Security to avoid non user access my app. I have to roles and passwords for this kind of users are encoded using SHA. All is working nice and I'm using the login form actively but I need a form to create users. My problem is that what I write in the password field is interpreted as an SHA encoded password so when I try to sign in with the new user, I can't. How can I solve this? Is there a way to force Spring to encrypt the password that I write in the password field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### At user authentication time

Spring security's authentication manager should be configured so that it encodes plain text passwords received from the login form using SHA beforehand.

This is explained in [this chapter](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#ns-auth-providers) of Spring Security's documentation, at the paragraph "Adding a Password Encoder". It is basically adding this line of configuration :

```
<authentication-provider>
    <password-encoder hash="sha"/>
    ...
</authentication-provider>
```

### At user creation time

Before you store a new user, you should encode "by yourself" the password, Spring security does not handle it.

In your case, you can use the `ShaPasswordEncoder.encodePassword(..)` method.

This topic was assessed in 
[Adding new users in Spring Security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2224873/adding-new-users-in-spring-security)

**Edit** added details after question author's first comment

Comment: No, password are stored ad plain text and that is what I need to change (I'm using Spring Data JPA). Spring Security is configured that way, so for example if a user was created with password 75BA66whatever792BD, when I write 123456 Spring grant me access.